# Between fingerprint unlock vs double-tap to wake up, what consumes more power?

Tags: lock-screens, battery-life, fingerprint

Due to past experiences with power buttons, I'm trying to almost not touch the power button (side key) except left with no option. So between these two alternatives of waking up a phone:

1. Using a fingerprint to unlock and wake up at the same time
2. Double-tap to wake up and then use a PIN to unlock)

What consumes more power of the two?

Comment: Fingerprint sensors are highly specialized hardware components with very little power consumption. Additionally entering the PIN takes additional time which means the display time is higher for a few seconds (and displays usually consume a lot power). So my guess would be using fingerprint is better to unlock. I also use my phone this way and then use double tap on launcher screen to re-lock (Nova Launcher feature).